# How large need n to be to ensure that Taylor polynomial around x=0 gives a value of sin(pi) which has an error of less than 0.001?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I've found different methods to calculate $n$, but all include that I test it for several $n$. Is it possible to make a general formula that gives me the answer without having to test it, or do I need to do it?

I have found $|\sin(\pi )-P_{2n+1}|\leq \frac{\pi ^{n+1}}{(2n+3)!}$
or $\frac{\pi ^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{1000}$, but this requires me to guess values for $n$ and then adjust. (It gives me $n$=11)

Is it possible to make a formula for any given error, or do I need to guess first and then again and again until I find it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your method is correct for finding the minimum value of $n$, however note that you want to have the term less than $\frac{1}{1000}$, so you should have an inequality. These inequalities can not always be solved algebraically, as in this example, so trial-and-error is an appropriate method to use.

Comment: Oh, I thought that I could use a complicated method to solve it algebraically, but I guess I just need to try and fail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want $n$ for which $E(n)=\pi^n/(2n+3)!<0.001$ which requires knowing some bounds for $\pi$, for example $ 223/71<\pi<22/7$ (Archimedes). If much greater precision is required for $E(n)$, there are approximation formulas for $m!$ for example ,for $m>0$ we have $$m!=(1+d(n))(n/e)^n \sqrt {2\pi n} \text {.... (Stirling)}$$ where  $0<d(n)<1/4n $  and $2.71<e<2.72$.